# Can't connect to network (wired/wireless), can't do anything about it?

Tags: windows, networking

I have a laptop (Sony Vaio Z running Windows 7) which won't connect to my work network. It was fine until a couple of weeks ago when we had a major network issue. The network and domain were rebuilt virtually from scratch, and every other machine migrated across fine.

This laptop, however, just won't. When starting the machine the wireless spinning circle icon appears for a while, then reverts to the "not connected" icon. Normally I'd go and clear out all the network settings and start again, but I'm unable to open either Manage Wireless Networks or Manage Devices to do so: both just hang indefinitely.

Is there any manual way to remove everything Windows knows about networks, and let it work it out itself, or am I looking at a full format? (Less than ideal, this is the bosses machine and I'd be interrupting him for too long at a busy time)

Comment: It would really help if you [edit] your question with what version of Windows you are running, what type of network (home or corporate) and what brand/model of computer. Details are important to getting good helpful answers.

Comment: I've added the OS and laptop make - I mentioned in the original question that it was on a domain and at work, so I figured people would assume a corporate network. Windows Sever 2012 runs DNS+DHCP, Ethernet through a switch and 802.11n via a different switch and a Draytek access point both have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a corporate issue which needs to be resolved by your IT staff and can be considered "off topic" here on SU. If you want to try to resolve it on your own here are 4 things you can do which may resolve your issue.

1. Run [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't anything else (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system.
2. Update definitions and run a complete virus scan. An additional free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its all gone might be a good idea.
3. Once you know the system is clean, open an elevated command prompt and run `SFC /SCANNOW` to run the [System File Check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833). When it is done, reboot.
4. If the issue still exists, you can reset TCP/IP to its original state by using the NetShell utility (netsh). [How to reset Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357)

Comment: I am the IT staff. It's a very small company and I've (somehow) acquired the network. Thanks for your suggestions, I'd already tried all 4, however, and none worked.

I fail to see how it's off topic. It's a question about a networking issue on a corporate network.